# "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE"

Tags: php, parsing

This is my code:

```
 <? php
     $content = file_get_contents("http://aux.iconpedia.net/uploads/1337412470.png");
     $fp = fopen("/test/image.jpg", "w");
     fwrite($fp, $content);
     fclose($fp);
 ?>
```

And this is the error I get:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in D:\Host\5164\html\maffick1\test\download.php on line 2

As far as I know, this error comes when you miss a semicolon or bracket. But I have tried everything.

Comment: Is this code in `download.php`? please put the code of `download.php` and mark the line no. 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove space between question mark and "php" in first line:

```
<? php
```

Change this to:

```
<?php
```

Answer (score 4):

Since `<?` also marks the beginning of a PHP script, the parser will treat your code as:

```
 <?
 php
 $content = file_get_contents("http://aux.iconpedia.net/uploads/1337412470.png");
 $fp = fopen("/test/image.jpg", "w");
 fwrite($fp, $content);
 fclose($fp);
 ?>
```

So it believes you're trying to declare a variable called `php`, but it's missing the `$` sign.

Remove the space:

```
 <?php
 $content = file_get_contents("http://aux.iconpedia.net/uploads/1337412470.png");
 $fp = fopen("/test/image.jpg", "w");
 fwrite($fp, $content);
 fclose($fp);
 ?>
```

Comment: Right answer, wrong interpretation of what it is trying to do - it is actually expecting `php` to be the name of a function that is being called, and would be expecting a `(` instead of a variable. It won't think your declaring a variable unless you use a `$`. But +1 for correct solution.