# Parse error Unexpected (, expected , in php when assign content file to a static property

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ‘.’, expecting ‘,’ or ‘;’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969342/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-expecting-or)

I have this class:

```
<?php

class MyClass {
  const DB_NAME  = "MyDb";

  const HOST = "localhost"; 

  const USER = "abcdef";

  const PASSWORD = "ghijklmn";

  public static $MyString = file_get_contents('file.txt');

}
?>
```

I have no idea what is wrong with `file_get_contents` ?

I cannot understand what is the error says ? Why `(` is unexpected ?

I read the following articles but these don't help me to solve that error:

[Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11785017/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-string-in-php)

[Parse error T_Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353629/parse-error-t-variable)

[file_get_contents shows unexpected output while reading a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720861/file-get-contents-shows-unexpected-output-while-reading-a-file)

Comment: You cannot initialize a class property with an expression or constant. The value has to be available at compile time.  Initialize it in a static `init()` method instead.

Comment: See the first paragraph [in these docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)

Comment: Even in a constructor ? Can I use in a constructor ?

Comment: Usually you initialize it in the contstructor, but since yours is static, you wouldn't necessarily be instantiating via a constructor first.  That's why I suggest a static `init()` method to initialize static properties. See the linked duplicate - there's a comparable example there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you have assigned expression to variable declaration. It can only use constants.

The workaround would be like this

```
<?php
class MyClass {
    ...
    public static $MyString;
    ...
}
MyClass::$MyString = file_get_contents('file.txt');
```

Comment: Ok, now I understand, that happens when I use C# for 3 years :))

Comment: This would return `Fatal error: Cannot access protected property MyClass::$MyString`

Comment: fine, replace protected with public...

Comment: better Still : http://pastebin.com/1bANsGry