# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting '(' on line 32

Tags: php, parsing, authentication, syntax-error

I'm trying to create a login page with sessions that differentiates between 2 types of users, "Admin" and "Sub" where each type of user will be directed to a different landing page upon a successful login. This is done by comparing username and password entered against the username and password in the database, where a match for both fields will result in a successful login.

The usernames and password entered by the user will be compared against values drawn from different tables which correspond to the differing types of users.

However, i am getting the error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting '(' on line 32. I've done some searching around StackOverflow and the closest answer i could find is from [Parse error Unexpected (, expected , in php when assign content file to a static property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874065/parse-error-unexpected-expected-in-php-when-assign-content-file-to-a-static) which doesn't seem to apply to me, from what i can make of it.Most of the questions i've seen on stack overflow regarding parse errors were due to people  forgetting to close their " } " or " ) ". However, i'm getting an error regarding an unexpected " { ", when a " ( " is expected. Why is this so???

My code is as follows:

```
<?php

session_start();
switch ($_POST[‘Button’])
{
case "Login":
    include("cxn.inc");
    $cxn=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db) or die("Can't connect to database");
    $query="SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username='$_POST[Username]'";
    $result=mysqli_query($cxn,$query) or die (" Cant find Username");
    $num=mysqli_num_rows($result);


        if($num>0)//Username is found
        {
            $query="SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Password='$_POST[Password]'";
            $result2=mysqli_query($cxn,$query)or die("Cant find Password");
            $num2=mysqli_num_rows($result2);
            if($num2>0)//Password is found
            {
                $_SESSION['Auth']="Yes";
                $_SESSION['Type']="Admin";
                header("Location:AdminMain.php");
            }
            else
            {
                echo"Invalid Username and/or Password";
            }

        }
        elseif//Executes when Username not found in Users table
        { <---This is the line giving me the error
            $query="SELECT * FROM SubUsers WHERE Username='$_POST[Username]'";
            $result3=mysqli_query($cxn,$query) or die(" Cant find Username");
            $num3=mysqli_num_rows($result3);
            if($num3>0)//Username is found
            {
                $query="SELECT * FROM SubUsers WHERE Password='$_POST[Password]'";
                $result4=mysqli_query($cxn,$query);
                $num4=mysqli_num_rows($result4);
                if($num4>0)//Password is found
                {
                    $_SESSION['Auth']="Yes";
                    $_SESSION['Type']="Sub";
                    header("Location:SubMain.php");
                }
                else
                {
                    echo"Cant find Password";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo"Cant find Username";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo"Invalid Username and/or Password entered";
        }
    include("LoginPage.php");

    break;
}
```

I would appreciate it if anyone could point out my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because if you use an `else if` then you will have to specify a condition.

Example

```
elseif($num == 0)
{
```

This will make it goes check if `> 0` then if `= 0` and else will be `< 0`

Comment: ...God i feel stupid now Lol. Thanks for pointing out that glaringly obvious mistake to me haha

Comment: @ken you welcome man! Don't forget to accept and upvote my answer to help people in the future with similar problems!